# producer and consumer problem with c++20 semaphore

Tags: c++, c++20, mutex, semaphore, producer-consumer

Here is producer and consumer problem implementation with c++20 semaphore adapted from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem. Do we still need std::lock_guardstd::mutex g(mtx);?

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <semaphore>

std::queue<int> q;
std::counting_semaphore<N> full{0};
std::counting_semaphore<N> empty{N};
std::mutex mtx;

void produce() {
  for (;;) {
    int item = 0;
    empty.acquire();
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(mtx);
      q.push(item);
    }
    full.release();
  }
}

void consume() {
  for (;;) {
    full.acquire();
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(mtx);
      int item = q.front();
      q.pop();
    }
    empty.release();
  }
}

int main() {
  std::thread t1(producer);
  std::thread t2(consumer);
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
}
```

As I understand, the semaphore has exclusion already. Why do we need another lock_guard?

Comment: Since you can keep producing stuff and consuming stuff in parallel while your are neither empty nor full. So the q.push/q.pop can still happen concurrently.  Think about the situation where N==4 and you are producing item #3 and consuming item #2

Comment: The semaphore provides mutual exclusion for the producer and consumer threads, but it does not protect the shared queue from concurrent access. The mutex is needed to ensure that only one thread can modify the queue at a time, otherwise there could be data corruption or inconsistency. The semaphore only controls how many threads can enter the critical section, but it does not guarantee atomicity of the operations inside the critical section. Therefore, you still need the lock_guard to acquire and release the mutex when you push or pop from the queue.

Comment: Anything shared with read/write access across threads should be locked.